# How to change ellipse function format?

Tags: functions

I already has ellipse function as below:

```
−3.06274x^2−y^2+1192.22x+152.71y+1.829648xy −196494==0
```

but I want to get the function like: `(x-h)^2/a^2+(y-k)^2/b^2=1`

How to transform the format?

Comment: If you expand `(x-h)^2/a^2+(y-k)^2/b^2=1` you'll see , there is no  part `x y`! So your problem concernes a rotated ellipse. Just look for `Matrix representation of conic sections`

Comment: `FullSimplify[-3.06274*x^2 - y^2 + 1192.22*x + 152.71*y + 1.829648*x*y - 196494 == 0]`gives `64156.3 + 1. x^2 + x (-389.266 - 0.597389 y) + (-49.8606 + 0.326505 y) y == 0`